# Combining "normal" commands in a function

Tags: vimrc

Suppose I have the following two lines in a function:

```
execute "normal! o"
execute "normal! S"
```

Is there a way to combine these so it is simpler, for example:

```
execute "normal! o<c-o>S"
```

It seems I need to 'escape' the `<c-o>` somehow.

Comment: Yes, escape `<c-o>` with `execute "normal! o\<C-o>S"`. See `:help expr-quote` which explains how double quoted strings work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `execute` parameters, you need to escape special characters sequences with `\`:

```
execute "normal o\<c-o>S"
```

But this will not let you in insert mode. You could add

```
startinsert
```

to force insert mode, but it will not respect `autoindent`. I don't know how to get around that.

---

You might as well go for a list of instructions:

```
normal! o
normal! S
startinsert
```

`execute` is no more needed, making the code quite clear.

Comment: sure, but wouldn't you need `execute "..."` if you're using any control sequence, such as in your first code line?

Comment: @David542 Yes, indeed. I edited my post to make it clearer what I meant.

Comment: You still want a bang on normal

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I'm not sure I understand the doc but I believe in you.

Comment: Well, typically it’s unlikely you want to use someone’s mapping for S when you do `:normal S` in a plugin—but without the bang, if I have `nnoremap S anything` it will take effect! Its like noremap for normal; it’s become something of a best-practice, and it’s good defensive programming. The idea is to use it unless you know you want to invoke a mapping via normal

Comment: Oh, I get it now, thanks for the clarification!